# Does Java win32 Native memory does not show in JProfiler, but shows in task manager

Tags: java

I am running an application written in C++ and it invokes a java class, written in C++ wrapper.

My C++ class calls the Java method: Execute(). 
Before this method call, in taskmanager i checks the memory for my application is around 40MB. The Execute() takes quite long time. When the Execute method invokes, i checked the taskmanager, and found the memory for my application is keep on increasing to almost 250MB and keep going. Since the memory rise happens while executing the Java API, so I run the JProfiler to check the memory consumption by the Java Module. I found the memory consumption for Java moule is approx 60MB.

So here I am trying to understand, how the task manager memory is keep on increasing. My C++ is a MFC application and a simple call to java API. So i dont think C++ is causing the issue.

My further analysis, I found that the JAVA API uses the WIn32 Native memory. So my question is here:
1. Is Task Manager memory is correct, any clue why it increases so much.
2. Since my Java module uses native memory, is it something like, the native memory shows in task manager not in Jprofiler.

Can you please provide support

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that Java memory system is totally different to the one from C++. Unused memory may not be reused until a full garbage collector run is executed which happens only from time to time. If you know how much memory is needed max, limit the JVM to this amount when you load it in your program.

This should be possible using the `maxHeapSize` of the `JDK1_1InitArgs` that you use in `JNI_CreateJavaVM`.

As you only need one long call you should also think of destroying the JVM after the call via `DestroyJavaVM();`. This should release all the memory used by the JVM.

Comment: Initialize java is set as 1024MB. But as I mentioned, the JProfiler says Java allocates 60MB only. So in ths case i dont understand, how task manager memory is rising.Is it something, because of native memory, which allocates in OS process space, due to this its not comming inder JProfiler but task manager shows.